# How To Prevent Firebase Firestore Emulator From Clearing The Database At Exit?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm Planning To Use Firebase - Firestore Emulators For Handling Some Huge Amount Of Data That's Coming From A Websocket.

I just need to process the data locally in realtime.

Firestore Emulator Is A great choice since it has all the features I need. But the issue is it clears the database every time the Emulator is turned off. is there any config or settings that can change this behaviour?

if it is not possible. can somebody tell me any other Approach to use firestore locally? or any other alternative to firebase that I can use locally.

Answer (score 25):

With the recent updates to Firebase Emulator, you use export the data when the emulator is running and import when it starts again.

To export the data

```
firebase emulators:export <export-directory>
```

To start and import the emulator

```
firebase emulators:start --import <export-directory>
```

Comment: You can now also add the [`--export-on-exit`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/install_and_configure) flag to automatically export data when you exit the emulator. Can't count how many times I lost a bunch of useful test data by exiting without remembering to export first!

Comment: @JamesAllen hi, can you point to documentation or tutorial on the update

Comment: Do not run `firebase emulators:export .`
It deletes everything in the folder if failed. Don't make the mistake I made. :)

Answer (score 20):

I've managed this starting Firebase emulator with parameters to export data on exit and import existing one:

```
firebase emulators:start --import=exported-dev-data --export-on-exit=exported-dev-data
```

This way the emulator always export the data I've generated to folder `exported-dev-data`, and loads it back when starting again.

Comment: you saved me a ton of time. Thanks!

Comment: @Bivis How are you stopping the emulators?  I'm running auth, firestore, and pub-sub.  I hit Ctrl+C in the same window I ran the emulators:start command in.  Pub-sub is never killed, none of the ports for firestore or auth are released, and sometimes I get a log that export was requested for a clean close, but sometimes there is no log at all after the ^C.  It imports data that I exported using a second firebase CLI, but never saves modified data.

Comment: @JeffNeet I am stopping the emulators like you, with Ctrl+C in the terminal window running the emulators. It takes a while but the emulators stop. But I'm not using Pub-sub, so I don't know if it is a bug in it.
But you can open another terminal window and export manually the data using "firebase emulators:export export-dev-data" command before trying to stop the emulators, and it will be loaded on the next launch with the above command

Comment: @Bivis thanks for the tip! I'll try exporting via a separate terminal.

Comment: The [emulator options](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/install_and_configure) add the ```./``` before the directory which didn't work for me. It also said leaving out a directory in either the ```--export-on-exit``` or ```import``` will default to the other, but only your solution worked.

Answer (score 2):

Currently you need to write code to populate the database during each run of the emulator.

If you would like to see different behavior, please [file an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools).

Answer (score 0):

1. If Emulator is running
   `firebase emulators:export <export-directory>`
2. If you want to start Emulator
   `firebase emulators:start --export-on-exit`
3. Importing Emulator Data
   `firebase emulators:start --import <export-directory>`
4. Importing & Export
   `firebase emulators:start --import <export-directory> --export-on-exit`